# AngularJS 1.5 How could I get event when something changes inside template component's

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Example - I have form with some inputs like:

```
<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.inputText">
<input type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.inputNumber">
</form>
```

My app based on components, so in my controller I need call event when data in my inputs has been changed.
Method $onChanges works only when binding var will be changed and won't affect when changes happen inside template.

Comment: what does your controller look like?

Comment: my controller is empty now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Controller:

```
 $scope.$watch("myForm.$dirty", function() {

    $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
 });
```

Html:

```
<form name="myForm">
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.inputText">
<input type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.inputNumber">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

```js
var myComponent = {
  scope: {},
  bindings: {},
  controller: function() {
    this.inputText = "boo";
    this.inputNumber = 666;
    this.changeEvent = function(val) {
      console.log("change event" + val);
    }
  },
  template: [
    '<form>',
      '<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.inputText" ng-change="$ctrl.changeEvent($ctrl.inputText)">',
      '<input type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.inputNumber">',
    '</form>'
  ].join('')
};

angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .component('myComponent', myComponent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes,right but if I need tracking all form, is it possible?